# XSD: how to reference types from external XSD without importing elements?

Tags: xml, xsd

Let's say we have two XML schemas **a.xsd** and **b.xsd** defined with the same namespace.

**a.xsd** contains the complex type "**myType**" definition as well as element "**A**".
**b.xsd** contains element **B** definition only.

I need to reference the myType in the b.xsd in order to define one of attributes of the element B..

As both the schemas belong to the same namespace, I used include statement like this in b.xsd:

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="a.xsd"></xs:include>
```

then, I can reference the type myType.
The issue however is that the element A is included into the schema B as well, which is not desirable as only one element B is expected to be presented in the schema.

So, is there a way to import or reference only types defined in an external schema without importing elements?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard W3C XML Schema specification provides no mechanism for only including or importing selected parts of another schema. The schemas are combined into a single infoset. It is possible to [redefine imported definitions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#modify-schema), so maybe you could do something with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really determined to achieve this, you could see if your chosen schema processor provides a user hook (some kind of URI resolver) to allow you intercept the xs:include request and return a filtered version of the referenced document.

Answer (score 0):

If myType is used by both Element A and Element B it should probably be in a third xsd. Often basic types that are being reused are collected in their own xsd, for example types.xsd. Then a.xsd and b.xsd both should import/include types.xsd to have access to the types they need without introducing unwanted elements.